# Dynamic html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

few font awesome classes not work during dynamic element with jquery

script(on click event)

[image: check the image]

```
 $('.chat-list li').removeClass('active');
 var chat_person = "<li id='1' class='active'><a href='#'><i class='fa fa-rocket'></i><span>" + player_name + "</span><i class='fa fa-times pull-right></i></a></li>";
 $(chat_person).insertAfter($(".chat-list li:first"));
```

Comment: Are you saying all of the "PlayerN Player" items should also have the "x"?

Comment: Yes bcoz i m appending all the div code  <li id='1' class='active'><a href='#'><i class='fa fa-rocket'></i><span>" + player_name + "</span><i class='fa fa-times pull-right></i></a></li>";

Comment: You are missing a closing `'` at the end of `class='fa fa-times pull-right`.

Comment: Thanks **david** Working fine now.

Answer (score -1):

You can not use jquery directly on a dynamic content jquery have "bind" method for this purpose

Comment: *"You can not use jquery directly on a dynamic content"* - Sure you can. (And regarding the `.bind()` method, it binds event handlers to elements that exist *at the time it is called*, not to elements that are added later.)

Comment: Working now **satyapal** there is a **'** was missing

Comment: My Bad, Misunderstood the question, I thought that the data is populated by Ajax call so suggested binding event handlers for that.